# Fail to make Laravel 4's Validator class work outside the framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to use Laravel'4 Eloquent outside of the framework, since the Illuminate/Database package as been made availabile stand-alone via composer.

Eloquent itself is working fine, but I'm blocked trying to implement validation rules.

I've tried first with some pre-built library like Ardent and then with my own code but the result it's the same, I got this fatal-error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on a non-object in
>   vendor\illuminate\support\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on
>   line 177

The problem always start when I call Validator::make();

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    $this->attributes,
    array('name' => 'required')
);
```

Looking in debug it seems that `static::resolveFacadeInstance('validator');` is called but it just return `null`.

I'm not familiar about how a Facades are meant to work, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "~4.0",
        "illuminate/validation" : "~4.0",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: Are installing it using Composer?

Comment: Yes, as I said Eloquent works well, I'll add my composer.json to the question...

Comment: What if you replace validation with `"illuminate/validation": "4.0.*@dev"` and database with `"illuminate/database": "4.0.*@dev"`?

Comment: Running "composer update" didn't update anything, so I guess I had already the latest version of the libraries. Anyway I don't think the problem lies in the libraries, but in how Laravel's facade system work. I think that I should initialize validator somewhere but I don't know how...

Comment: I think your problem is related to this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/854

Comment: Yes, I also posted on github's issue, got a reply minutes ago, check it out!

Comment: Ah, didn't notice this is you. :)

Answer (score 4):

For people who may need more information I'll report here the answer given to me on laravel's github repo by **bencorlett** [(link)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/854):

```
// Store the factory instance somewhere, Maybe like:

class Validator {

    protected static $factory;

    public static function instance()
    {
        if ( ! static::$factory)
        {
            $translator = new Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator('en');
            static::$factory = new Illuminate\Validation\Factory($translator);
        }

        return static::$factory;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $instance = static::instance();

        switch (count($args))
        {
            case 0:
                return $instance->$method();

            case 1:
                return $instance->$method($args[0]);

            case 2:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);

            case 3:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);

            case 4:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);

            default:
                return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
        }
    }
}

$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

Answer (score 4):

I've got it working in a project that I'm working on. Unfortunately, the documentation on how to use it outside of the framework is non-existent. The documentation for how to use Eloquent outside of the framework at least exists, but is dodgy.

So first, put it in composer.json:

```
"illuminate/validation": "4.1.*",
```

The validation object is made by a factory object. This factory object is what the facade maps back to. So instead of using the facade, get that object like so:

```
$factory = new \Illuminate\Validation\Factory(new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator('en'));
```

You can then `make` your validation object:

```
$validator = $factory->make($inputArray, $rulesArray);
```

There are a couple of caveats to using this outside of the framework that I've found so far.

The first is that any database-dependent validations will fail, since it has no way to query the database. This is resolved by giving the validation object a `Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier` object which wraps the database manager that you can get from the object that you made when setting up Eloquent:

```
$validator->setPresenceVerifier(new \Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier($capsule->getDatabaseManager());
```

The other one is that the default validation messages are not set up. So far, I've handled this just by using the third argument to the `make` function to specify per-field custom rules.